# Can I build a lightning component to call/open a quick action in 2017?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, quickaction

We really need a way to invoke an existing quick action on a record programmatically. I know that we can close it (e.g.  `$A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction").fire();` ), is there a way to open it or embed it in my own component?

Comment: If you need to call a create quick action or an edit action, you can use these events: [`force:createRecord`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_createRecord.htm) and [`force:editRecord`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_editRecord.htm)

Comment: Thanks Martin, but we just want to call custom quick actions.

Comment: If this is custom quick action, is this not supposed to be custom Lightning components? If so, you can use the [`force:navigateToComponent`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_navigateToComponent.htm) event.